# Is it possible to use python suds to read a wsdl file from the file system?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

From suds [documentation](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#BASICUSAGE), I can create a `Client` if I have a url for the WSDL.

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://localhost:7080/webservices/WebServiceTestBean?wsdl'
client = Client(url)
```

I currently have the WSDL file on my file system.  Is it possible to use suds to read the WSDL file from my file system instead of hosting it on a web server?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

try to use `url='file:///path/to/file'`

Comment: To add to Thierry's comment, it also has to be an absolute path. (eg. file:///home/admin/service.xml)

Answer (score 19):

#### Oneliner

```
# Python 3
import urllib, os 
url = urllib.parse.urljoin('file:', urllib.request.pathname2url(os.path.abspath("service.xml")))
```

This is a more complete one liner that will:

- let you specify just the local path,
- get you the absolute path,
- and then format it as a file-url.

Based upon:

- the comments in the accepted answer and
- this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298190/622276
- and thanks to user [Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2051646/sebastian) the updated Python 3 implementation since we should avoid writing legacy python at this time.

#### Original for reference

```
# Python 2 (Legacy Python)
import urlparse, urllib, os

url = urlparse.urljoin('file:', urllib.pathname2url(os.path.abspath("service.xml")))
```

Comment: In case someone is using python3, the names have changed:
`import urllib, os`
`url = urllib.parse.urljoin('file:', urllib.request.pathname2url(os.path.abspath("service.xml")))`

Comment: that solved my problem that appeared when switching from python 3.8.x to 3.9.2

Answer (score 2):

Using pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path
url = Path('resources/your_definition.wsdl').absolute().as_uri()
```