# Convert a filename to a file:// URL

Tags: python, url, filenames

In WeasyPrint’s public API I accept filenames (among other types) for the HTML inputs. Any filename that works with the built-in `open()` should work, but I need to convert it to an URL in the `file://` scheme that will later be passed to `urllib.urlopen()`.

(Everything is in URL form internally. I need to have a "base URL" for documents in order to resolve relative URL references with `urlparse.urljoin()`.)

[urllib.pathname2url](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.pathname2url) is a start:

> Convert the pathname path from the local syntax for a path to the form used in the path component of a URL. **This does not produce a complete URL.** The return value will already be quoted using the quote() function.

The emphasis is mine, but I do need a complete URL. So far this seems to work:

```py
def path2url(path):
    """Return file:// URL from a filename."""
    path = os.path.abspath(path)
    if isinstance(path, unicode):
        path = path.encode('utf8')
    return 'file:' + urlparse.pathname2url(path)
```

UTF-8 seems to be recommended by [RFC 3987 (IRI)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987). But in this case (the URL is meant for urllib, eventually) maybe I should use [sys.getfilesystemencoding()](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding)?

However, based on [the literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) I should prepend not just `file:` but `file://` ... except when I should not: On Windows the results from `nturl2path.pathname2url()` already start with three slashes.

So the question is: is there a better way to do this and make it cross-platform?

Comment: Couldn't you just check for something like `url[0:2] == '///'`, and if false add the two extra slashes?

Comment: Joachim, maybe that would work. I just don’t know what rules to follow to avoid surprising corner-cases.

Comment: Hey, your example code uses `urlparse.pathname2url`, which doesn't exist.  Did you mean `urllib.pathname2url`?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

For completeness, in Python 3.4+, you should do:

```
import pathlib

pathlib.Path(absolute_path_string).as_uri()
```

Comment: This module is also on PyPI (for other Python versions) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/

Comment: [pathlib2](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/) should now be used for other Python versions

Comment: `as_uri()`  doesn't work on relative filenames (there are use cases for converting only partial filename to (partial) URL

Comment: Relative URLs can be easily supported using pathlibs `resolve()` function, e.g. `pathlib.Path(src).resolve().as_uri()`

Answer (score 33):

I'm not sure the docs are rigorous enough to guarantee it, but I think this works in practice:

```
import urlparse, urllib

def path2url(path):
    return urlparse.urljoin(
      'file:', urllib.pathname2url(path))
```

Comment: Tested on Linux, Windows, and OS X and it works fine on all three.

Comment: And in py3k this becomes `import urlib.parse as urlparse` and `import urlib.request as urllib`

Comment: you should probably call `os.path.abspath(path)` here.

Comment: If you use the [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) library to assure Python 2 and 3 portability: 
    `return six.moves.urllib_parse.urljoin(
        "file://", six.moves.urllib.request.pathname2url(path))`

Comment: This produces urls that look like `file:///C:/foo%20bar/spam/eggs"` Shouldn't it be `file:///C%3A/foo%20bar/spam/eggs"` with the colon turned into `%3A`?

Comment: @stib: aparently not, not on Windows, where the drive letter colon is to be kept intact. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Windows_2

Answer (score 5):

Credit to comment from `@danodonovan` above.

For Python3, the following code will work:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from urllib.request import pathname2url

def path2url(path):
    return urljoin('file:', pathname2url(path))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work for you?

```
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse

urlunparse(urlparse('yourURL')._replace(scheme='file'))
```

Comment: The idea is interesting, but I don’t know if this is enough. In particular, `\` in Windows filenames is supposed to become `/`. Still on Windows, The C in `C:\foo\bar.html` is parsed as a scheme and then replaced. The expected output would be `file:///C:/foo/bar.html`.