# In Python 3, how do I convert a file:// URL to an OS path with code that works in both Linux and Windows?

Tags: python, file, url, path

Here is code that demonstrates the problem when converting a file:// URL to an OS path.

```
import os
import pathlib
import sys
import urllib.parse

print ("sys.argv[0]      = {0}".format(sys.argv[0]))

varFilename = sys.argv[0]
varFilename = os.path.abspath(varFilename)
print ("abs varFilename  = {0}".format(varFilename))

varMainFolder = os.path.dirname(varFilename)
print ("varMainFolder    = {0}".format(varMainFolder))

varTarget = os.path.join(varMainFolder,"test test.py")
print ("varTarget        = {0}".format(varTarget))

varURL = pathlib.Path(varTarget).as_uri()
print ("varURL           = {0}".format(varURL))

varPathRaw = urllib.parse.urlparse(varURL).path
print ("varPathRaw       = {0}".format(varPathRaw))

varPathDecode = urllib.parse.unquote(varPathRaw)
print ("varPathDecode    = {0}".format(varPathDecode))

varOSPath = os.path.normpath(varPathDecode)
print ("varOSPath        = {0}".format(varOSPath))
```

In Linux, this code prints:

```
sys.argv[0]      = test.py
abs varFilename  = /home/ldbader/test.py
varMainFolder    = /home/ldbader
varTarget        = /home/ldbader/test test.py
varURL           = file:///home/ldbader/test%20test.py
varPathRaw       = /home/ldbader/test%20test.py
varPathDecode    = /home/ldbader/test test.py
varOSPath        = /home/ldbader/test test.py
```

Notice the varOSPath is a perfectly valid absolute path.  But in Windows, the code prints:

```
sys.argv[0]      = test.py
abs varFilename  = C:\mli\Junk\test.py
varMainFolder    = C:\mli\Junk
varTarget        = C:\mli\Junk\test test.py
varURL           = file:///C:/mli/Junk/test%20test.py
varPathRaw       = /C:/mli/Junk/test%20test.py
varPathDecode    = /C:/mli/Junk/test test.py
varOSPath        = \C:\mli\Junk\test test.py
```

Notice that varOSPath has an absolute path preceded by an invalid backslash. Attempting to open a file with this path will fail.  I would have expected os.path.normpath() to discard a slash to the left of a drive specification, but it doesn't.

What should I do so the same logic gives me a valid absolute path on both platforms?

Comment: Do any of the suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687478/convert-a-filename-to-a-file-url) help out?

Comment: No. I have no problem building platform dependent file:/// URLs.  The problem is opening a file using a path taken from a file:/// URL.

Comment: Ah ha! Three slashes before Windows path! Tricky - thanks for this map!

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is my answer.  It appears to work for my scenarios, but I am not sure what will happen if a Linux user creates a folder named /C: (or any other name that looks like a Windows drive letter).

```
import os
import pathlib
import sys
import urllib.parse

print ("sys.argv[0]      = {0}".format(sys.argv[0]))

varFilename = sys.argv[0]
varFilename = os.path.abspath(varFilename)
print ("abs varFilename  = {0}".format(varFilename))

varMainFolder = os.path.dirname(varFilename)
print ("varMainFolder    = {0}".format(varMainFolder))

varTarget = os.path.join(varMainFolder,"test test.py")
print ("varTarget        = {0}".format(varTarget))

varURL = pathlib.Path(varTarget).as_uri()
print ("varURL           = {0}".format(varURL))

varPathRaw = urllib.parse.urlparse(varURL).path
print ("varPathRaw       = {0}".format(varPathRaw))

varPathDecode = urllib.parse.unquote(varPathRaw)
print ("varPathDecode    = {0}".format(varPathDecode))

varOSPath = os.path.normpath(varPathDecode)
print ("varOSPath        = {0}".format(varOSPath))

varFixedPath = varOSPath
varDrive = os.path.splitdrive(varFixedPath[1:])[0]
print ("varDrive         = {0}".format(varDrive))
if varDrive:
    varFixedPath = varFixedPath[1:]
print ("varFixedPath     = {0}".format(varFixedPath))
```

The trick is to use os.path.splitdrive() on the absolute path after removing the first character.  For a Windows absolute path, it will return the drive specification.  For a Linux absolute path, it will return an empty string.  If the drive specification is an empty string, use the absolute path as is.  If the drive specification is **not** an empty string, remove the first character from the absolute path and use the result.

I still believe that the os.path.normpath() method should not return an absolute Windows path with a leading backslash.